# Rust can't find 'crate' for 'std'

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-cargo

I'm trying to get a .wasm file via `RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown` but get the error:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
```

When i type `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown` i get:

```
info: component 'rust-std' for target 'wasm32-unknown-unknown' is up to date
```

I installed Rust and Rustup separate via chocolatey.

- rustc 1.58.0
- rustup 1.24.3
- info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.60.0-nightly (5e57faa78 2022-01-19)`

Comment: Seem to remember you need to run without the std lib for wasm.  Details here: https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/intro/no-std.html

Comment: @wobr std works with wasm32-unknown-unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the wasm32-unknown-unknown target for the nightly toolchain if that's what you are using:

```
rustup target add --toolchain nightly wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

Answer (score 3):

I suffered the same symptoms after initialized a new cargo project on macOS but my problem was not adding to the wrong toolchain.

In my case, the problem was multiple cargo binaries. I discovered this after running `which cargo` and seeing it installed via homebrew. I did `rustup self uninstall` (perhaps unnecessary), `brew uninstall rust`, and then reinstalled rust [according to the official docs](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install) and `wasm32-unknown-unknown` and then the `cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown` command worked as expected.